# Getting an EOF error for a user input statement

Tags: python, python-3.9

I just started coding with python for school a few weeks ago and as a part of my assignment I need to make a chatbot. When submitting it into the grader, I get this error back:

```
Test Failed: b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/autograder/source/q1.py", line 17, in <module>\n    mood = input("How are you doing today?\\n")\nEOFError: EOF when reading a line\n'
```

```
good_mood_set = {"Good", "I’m great", "I’m good", "Fine"}
bad_mood_set = ("Bad", "Not Okay", "I’m not feeling good")
mood = input("How are you doing today?\n")
if mood in bad_mood_set:
    print("Have some time to yourself to recharge!")
elif mood in good_mood_set:
    print("I’m glad you’re feeling well, " + name + ".")
else:
    print("I see!")
age = input("How old are you?\n")
if mood in good_mood_set and age >= "18":
    print("You are ready to drive.\n")
else:
    print("Still taking the bus!\n")
```

The goal for this segment is for the chatbot to receive any of the responses in good_mood_set and bad_mood_set and then respond accordingly. In the IDE terminal, it worked out perfectly fine. This is what my code was when I got the error. I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. I had gotten an error similar to this one except it was:

```
name = input()
```

where it is intended for user input. I fixed it by putting the input line into a function and making name a global variable so it can be used outside the function, but I'm stumped for this one. Any help help on how to solve this error/ revisions to my code would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Why do you use a set for `good_mood_set`, but a tuple for `bad_mood_set`?  Why not make them both sets?

Comment: Also, you're trying to treat strings as numbers.  In your code, `age` is a string, and `age >= "18"` is comparing them as strings, not numbers (e.g. `"2"` will be greater than `"18"`, which isn't what you want).  Change it to `age = int(input("How old are you?\n"))` and `if mood in good_mood_set and age >= 18:`  That way `age` will be an integer and the comparison will compare integers.

Comment: _When submitting it into the grader_ If your code is running inside a grader, it probably doesn't have normal access to keyboard input.  I bet there are special instructions for providing user input in the grader.  Ask your teacher.

Comment: @TomKarzes oh that was a mistake, i meant for both to be sets. thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for the suggestion to change my code, I will implement that in my revision

Comment: @JohnGordon unfortunately my teacher is very sparse on the details outside of the assignment document he gave us. he says, "• For the third question, Pchatbot should be prepared to accept two categories of answers from the
user and react accordingly"  the two categories being my good_mood_set and bad_mood_set